# Using Docker Containers With User Sessions & SSH in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, docker

I am looking for some help on how to dockerize user sessions in Linux. What I am looking for is how would I make it so when someone ssh's into an account and does anything, when they exit anything they did isn't saved; it's how I have it set up next time someone else ssh's into it.

It's for a CTF event I've been tasked with setting up and with really no knowledge of most of what I have to do this whole process is a learning experience for me.

A good explanation of how I am hoping to have it set up is explained here: http://overthewire.org/help/sshinfra.html

Any help or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this good/close enough?
https://github.com/Yelp/dockersh

Otherwise this might help you build a more specific solution:
http://jonaskunze.com/restrict-user-to-its-own-container-using-docker/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response I've been trying to figure it out.  I tried running both links actually.  The first one has errors with building the docker and it doesn't seem to have a fix.

The second one I actually got up and running but I need to figure out how to create the home directory in the container somehow and have the user start in their home directory when they ssh and not in "/"

Comment: Depending on which solution in the second link you chose (1, 2 or 3, where my suggestion would be 1 or 3), you don't really NEED separate directories;  the users already exists in separate containers. If you still WANT a home-directory for the user in the user-specific container, just set that up in your dockerfile, preferably with an ARG-setting.